# How to specifically check value of order of AR or MA in ARIMA using auto.arima function for time series data using R

Tags: r, arima

How do I check what the order of `q` of `MA(q)` or `p` of `AR(p)` or `p` alone in `ARIMA(p,d,q)` or q in `ARIMA(p,d,q)`. If I simulate a time series data with `arima.sim` like this.

```
sim <- arima.sim(n=100, list(order = c(1, 0, 1), ar=0.7, ma=-0.3), sd=sqrt(1))

mis <- auto.arima(sim)
```

I want a function like `p<-function(mis,...)` or `q<-function(mis,...)` or `d<-function(mis,...)` that will print out 1 for p or 1 for q and 0 for d

How do I save the values of `p,q,d` seperately so I can call each for reuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to get back the `order=` of the simulation consistently, since the results of `auto.arima` may differ. However the `auto.arima` result is stored inside `mis$arma`.

```
set.seed(42)
sim <- arima.sim(list(order=c(1, 0, 1), ar=0.7, ma=-0.3), sd=sqrt(1), n=100)
mis <- auto.arima(sim)
mis
# Series: sim 
# ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   ar1
# 0.4188
# s.e.  0.0903
# 
# sigma^2 estimated as 0.9638:  log likelihood=-139.65
# AIC=283.29   AICc=283.41   BIC=288.5
fun <- function(x) setNames(x$arma[c(1, 6, 2)], c("p", "d", "q"))
fun(mis)
# p d q 
# 1 0 0
```

The function can be extended to `switch` between the `order=` elements:

```
fun2 <- function(x, v) {
  if (!v %in% c("p", "d", "q"))
  stop('v has to be in c("p", "d", "q")')
  r <- x$arma
  setNames(switch(v, p=r[1], d=r[6], q=r[2]), v)
}
fun2(mis, "p")
# p 
# 1
```

You may also use:

```
fun2(mis, "d")
fun2(mis, "q")
```

You see, the result of the function at least corresponds with the output of `auto.arima`. You may check this with other `set.seed`s to vary the results.

The explanation of the `c(1, 6, 2)` order can be derived from the "Value" section of the `?arima` help page, which instructs to decipher `mis$arma` as follows:

```
setNames(mis$arma,
         c("AR", "MA", "seas.AR", "seas.MA", 
           "period", "n.seas.dif", "seas.dif"))
# AR         MA    seas.AR    seas.MA     period n.seas.dif   seas.dif 
# 1          0          0          0          1          0          0
```

Comment: great! How can I have a function that print only the value of p? such that instead of 1 i can just run p

Comment: so that if i need to check if the value of p is greater than 1 i can run `if p>1`

Comment: @DanielJames Notice, that `set.seed` must be set on line above before the simulation, I've corrected that.

Comment: @DanielJames See edit, with `fun2` you can select either the value for p, d or q.

Comment: you are right, but how can i hack it such  `p` or `q` or `d` will not appear in my answer but only the value?

Comment: @DanielJames You can use `unname(fun2(mis, "p"))`. If that's too cumbersome cou could discard the `setNames()`, i.e. replace last line of `fun2` with just `switch(v, p=r[1], d=r[6], q=r[2])`.

Comment: can you also show me how to specifically get `RMSE` alone in `ARIMA` model?

Comment: @DanielJames I think you're looking for `?forecast::accuracy`.

Comment: yes. I need a function as you gave for `p,d,q` to call a name so I can use it for another test in another r program

Comment: Audinarillay, I can get it in `miss<-summary(auto.arima(sim))` but it will include other forecasting accuracy metrics like `ME`, `MAE`, `MAPE`, `MPE` etc which I do not need here

Comment: @DanielJames I see. You might try to write such a function yourself, based e.g. on this answer, and if you get stuck, it's probably better to ask a new question.

Comment: yes, I will ask a new question on that and put the link here for you to see

Comment: check the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994644/how-to-specifically-check-value-of-rmse-of-ar-or-ma-in-arima-using-auto-arima-fu